# Spring Security XML Configuration and setting permissions

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am trying to configure a filter to run for pre authentication to my web app using Ping Federate. I want this filter to be ran when all resources are being accessed, except for '/login'.

That is, every page should go through a filter except '/login'.

I am using Spring Security 3.2 and I understand that using

```
<security:http pattern="/login" auto-config="true" security="none">
```

is the new way to write

```
<intercept-url pattern="/login*" filters="none" />
```

However, when adding security='none' to my XML config file, the filter is still being picked up when I access localhost:8080/login.

Below is my XML configuration file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.2.xsd">

    <context:annotation-config />
    <context:property-placeholder />

    <security:global-method-security
        pre-post-annotations="enabled" />
    <bean id="resourceLoader" class="com.foo.bar.ResourceLoader">
        <constructor-arg value="${PING_IDENTITY_CONFIG_FILE_NAME}" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="openTokenReader" class="com.foo.bar.OpenTokenReader" />



    <security:http pattern="/login" use-expressions="true" security="none" />



    <security:http use-expressions="true" auto-config="true"
        entry-point-ref="http403EntryPoint">
        <security:custom-filter position="PRE_AUTH_FILTER"
            ref="openTokenFilter" />
        <security:session-management
            invalid-session-url="/login" />
        <security:session-management>
            <security:concurrency-control
                max-sessions="1" error-if-maximum-exceeded="true" />
        </security:session-management>
        <security:logout />
    </security:http>


    <bean id="openTokenFilter"
        class="com.foo.bar.OpenTokenRequestAuthenticationFilter">
        <property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager" />
        <property name="logoutURL" value="${PING_IDENTITY_LOGOUT_URL}" />
        <property name="authenticationFailureHandler">
            <bean
                class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler">
                <property name="defaultFailureUrl" value="/login" />
            </bean>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="preauthAuthProvider"
        class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.preauth.PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider">
        <property name="preAuthenticatedUserDetailsService">
            <bean id="userDetailsServiceWrapper"
                class="org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsByNameServiceWrapper">
                <property name="userDetailsService" ref="customUserDetailsService" />
            </bean>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <security:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
        <security:authentication-provider
            ref="preauthAuthProvider" />
    </security:authentication-manager>

    <bean id="customUserDetailsService" class="com.foo.bar.UserDetailsServiceImpl"></bean>
    <bean id="http403EntryPoint"
        class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.Http403ForbiddenEntryPoint"></bean>

</beans>
```

I have tried nearly everything I can think of and for something that should be completely straightforward I have been unable to figure out the issue for quite some time.

Comment: Do you have suffix like '.do' on mapping to your controller methods?

Comment: No I do not, should I?

Comment: No. Can you provide servlet mapping config from web.xml?

Comment: I'm using spring boot, so I don't have a web.xml file..starting to think that might be part of the problem

Comment: Okey, show config where you initialize your servlet.

Comment: Or you can try this solution, remove attribute filters and add this access="permitAll". Filters="none" is deprecated from 3.1 version.

Comment: Access is not a valid attribute for the http namespace so it throws an error. And I don't have any servlet code I'm using what spring boot already has configured out of the box

Comment: Provide please example of url for yours any controller.

Comment: Yeah that is what I originally had, check my XML file. It seems that setting that to none should void the URL of any filters, but it does not

Comment: My web app has 'http://localhost:8080/home', 'http://localhost:8080/session', 'http://localhost:8080/login' etc...all of which should be protected except the login page

Comment: Try set up option auto-config="false"

Comment: Unfortunately that didnt seem to make a difference, im stumped